# How to call part of a form by Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a form with lots of boxes. I want to add a field of checkbox as the values come from a php file via Ajax call. How to handle a form within another form?

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<input ...

-------Inner form (imaginary form to perform Ajax call)
TYPE YOUR COUNTRY AND POPULATE CITY
(here user types a country and we populate cities from city.php?q=typed-country. 
City will return by the output of city.php file. In other words, output of 
city.php is exactly list of cities, which can be formatted with required 
CHECKBOX codes)
List of cities as CHECKBOX; e.g.
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="city1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="city2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="city3" />
--------

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

There are example of two select field for capturing cities for selected country; but here I need TYPE INPUT for country and CHECKBOX for resulting cities.

Comment: You've got to tell us how you're returning the list of cities. Give a sample output. Also, I think you mean city.php?q=typed-country

Comment: @Amaan you were right about the typo. The php part is not my problem, I can handle it in any way needed; my problem is related to javascript part. I exampled further.

Comment: I don't quite get the last sentence. You get the country using a select element and you want to show the user the returned cities using checkboxes. Is that correct? And as Derek says, your HTML seems wrong. You cannot have an 'inner form.' You don't need the inner form since you're using AJAX.

Comment: No Select! Users type the country (a text input form), and the list of cities will be provided to them as checkbox list.

Comment: Alright. I have answered your question assuming you will return the cities separated by commas, and you have a div with the id citiesListContainer where you want to display your checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('GET','cities.php?q='+document.getElementById('country').value,true);
ajax.send();
citiesList = new Array();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4){
        citiesList = ajax.responseText.split(',');
    }
}
for(var i=0;i<citiesList.length;i++){
document.getElementById('citiesListContainer').innerHTML+='<input type="checkbox" value="'+citiesList[i]+'" /> '+citiesList[i]+'<br>';
}
```

Use the above code where your query returns a list of cities, with each city being separated by a comma. In your HTML, you have a div, with the id citiesListContainer.
You could also use the appendChild method to add each individual checkbox, but mine is the lazy man's answer.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh4qy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a form inside of a form. You can make the entire form submit (and just use necessary data) or separate the two forms.

Comment: No it's just explaining the issue. Because I cannot have a form inside another form, I am asking how can I provide a list of checkboxes within my form came from an Ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

use .change on the country

```
$("#country").change(function () {    
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {        
        var value = $(this).value()
        ajax to your php, return info you need
            modify/build your city information
    });    
})
```

that would example would be for a select box, however the principle of using .change would be the same for any type, though you wouldn't need the select option:selected.each bit